# How do I plot inside a for loop? Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a straight line from a point in x to different values of t, thereby making a line in a for loop. But I see no lines generated in my figure in MATLAB

Following is my code:

```
 t=linspace(0,8,11)
xs=(1.+t).^0.5
x0=xs./(1.+t)
m=size(t)
n=max(m)
hold on
for k=1:n
plot(x0(k),t(1:k),'-')
 hold on
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting graph using for loop in MatLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539883/plotting-graph-using-for-loop-in-matlab)

Comment: @Cris I do not think this is a duplicate. Your dupe target says why the plot does not show anything, but it does not solve OPs problem. According to his top line he wants to plot a line from x to t.

Comment: @Rahul neither `x` or `t` are points, they are values. What is their other coordinate?

Comment: @NickyMattsson: I probably misunderstood the problem. Re-reading, I don’t understand at all what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the loop to perform the plot.

```
plot(x0,t,'-')
```

Will work just fine! Unless you were attempting to plot points...use `scatter()` for that:

```
scatter(x0,t)
```

`plot()` and `scatter()` (and most of Matlab's functions) are meant to be used with vectors, which can take some time to get used to if you are used to traditional programming languages. Just as you didn't need a loop to create the vector `x0`, you don't need a loop to use `plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding one point in Y axis along a line in X Axis use this code

```
t=linspace(0,8,11)
xs=(1.+t).^0.5
x0=xs./(1.+t)
m=size(t)
n=max(m)
hold on
for k=1:n
plot(x0(1:k),t(1:k),'-')
hold on
end
```

for more fun and see exactly how for is performed use this for loop

```
for k=1:n
pause('on')
plot(x0(1:k),t(1:k),'-')
hold on
pause(2)
end
```